# Nginx: Nuxtjs app on main domain + WordPress in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, nuxt.js

I have a nuxtjs app https://damjanun.com/ running on main domain with nginx proxy setup. Now we need to install wordpress inside a sub-directory i.e: https://damjanun.com/blog . I can't get it done.

Comment: You can try the static directory.

Comment: @tomshaw not working

Comment: I've tried the equivalent with an Angular/Zend setup once it worked fine. The recommended setup is to use a Monorepo + keep the domains/projects separated deployment wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Here is my nginx config file for damjanun.com. The blog also works fine https://damjanun.com/blog

```
location /blog {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: Can you pls provide a complete config